# Administrator privileges in VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, windows-server

I've created the repository and add the users to access it.

- How to add the full access rights to the administrator in VisualSVN Server?
- How can I add the administrator to access all the privileges compared to the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Full access to manage VisualSVN Server via VisualSVN Server Management console requires the user to be a member of local *VisualSVN Server Admins* group. Users who are members of this group have full access to manage repositories, authorization access rules and server settings. For instructions on configuring the remote administration feature see the article ["Configuring Remote Administration"](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00025/).

  [image: ServerManagerMMC]

---

- VisualSVN Server 2.7+ allows you to assign non-administrators as *repository supervisors* (i.e. managers). Supervisors don't have full access to administer VisualSVN Server but can manage authorization access rules for particular repositories. Access rules management is done via [VisualSVN Repository Configurator tool](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/delegation/) remotely.

  [image: RepoCfg]